# Build android app with specific debug/release key with specific password

Tags: android, debugging, build, keystore

I have an android source code also I have specific debug and release .keystore files and specific passwords to them. How I can build the sources with this keystores and passwords using eclipse? When I try add custom debug keystore it will notified that "`Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect`". Where can I specify the password in eclipse and how can I build app with this keystore?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And also how to build source code with specific `.properties`? How to specify property file that must be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use your release .keystore file in Eclipse select the export option and export it as Android Application. It will ask you for you .keystore file and password on the next screens

[image: Export Android Application]

Answer (score 1):

According to the Android Developers [site](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

> If necessary, you can change the location/name of the debug
>   keystore/key or supply a custom debug keystore/key to use.  However,
>   any custom debug keystore/key must use the same keystore/key names and
>   passwords as the default debug key (as described above).

So if your debug key does not use these names and passwords, you cannot use it:

> Keystore name: "debug.keystore"  Keystore password: "android"  Key
>   alias: "androiddebugkey"  Key password: "android"  CN: "CN=Android
>   Debug,O=Android,C=US"

To use your release keystore, you can open your AndroidManifest.xml, click on the manifest tab at the bottom, and scroll down and click on the Export Wizard. Here you can browse to your release keystore and supply the alias and passwords.

Comment: Why I can't specify alias and password for debug.keystore?

Comment: @LazyBeard I do not know. I'm assuming to prevent people from releasing their applications that have been signed by a debug key.